# Improve Bash script to obtain file names, remove part of their names, and display the result until a key is entered

Tags: string, bash

I have fully working code that obtains a list of file names from the '$testDir', removes the final 3 characters from each, runs a different script using the adjusted names, and displays a list of the edited names that had errors when used in the seperate script, until the letter 'q' is entered by the user.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Declarations
declare -a testNames
declare -a errorNames
declare -a errorDescription
declare resultDir='../Results'
declare outputCheck=''
declare userEntry=''
declare -i userSelect

# Obtain list of files in $resultDir and remove the last 3 chars from each file name
for test in `ls $resultDir`; do
    testNames+=("${test::-3}")
done

# Run 'checkFile.sh' script for each adjusted file name and add name and result to apporopriate arrays if 'checkFile.sh' script fails
for f in "${testNames[@]}"; do
    printf '%s' "$f: "
    outputCheck=$(./scripts/checkFile.sh -v "${f}" check)
    if [[ $outputCheck != "[0;32mNo errors found.[0m" ]];
        then
            errorNames+=("$f")
            errorDescription+=("$outputCheck")
            echo -e '\e[31mError(s) found\e[0m'
        else
            printf '%s\n' "$outputCheck"
    fi
done

#Prompts user to save errors, if any are present
if [ "${#errorNames[@]}" != 0 ];
then
    until [[ $userEntry  = "q" ]]; do
        echo "The following tests had errors:"
        for(( i=1; i<=${#errorNames[@]}; i++ )); do
            echo -e $i: "\e[31m${errorNames[i-1]}\e[0m"
        done

        echo "Enter the corresponding number in the list to save the errors found or enter 'q' to quit"
        read -r userEntry
        numInput=$userEntry
        if [ $numInput -gt 0 -a $numInput -le ${#errorNames[@]} ];
            then
                mkdir -p ./Errors
                echo -e "File" "\e[96m${errorNames[$userEntry-1]}""_Error_Info.txt\e[0m created in the 'Errors' folder which contains details of the error(s)"
                echo "${errorDescription[$userEntry-1]}" > "./Errors/""${errorNames[$userEntry-1]}""_Error_Info.txt"
        fi
    done

    echo 'Successfully Quit'
    exit $?
fi
echo 'No errors found'
exit $?
```

As someone who is new to Bash and programming concepts, I would really appreciate any suggested improvements to this code. In particular, the script needs to run quickly as the 'checkFile.sh' script takes a long time to run itself. I have a feeling the way I have written the code is not concise either.

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), rather use process substitution syntax.

Comment: Looks like a good fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better appropriate in [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: My apologies, I did not realise Code Review existed. If people agree the question should be posted there, I shall delete this question and migrate it